# How to aggregate journal entries for last boot

Tags: journalctl

I have centralized journals from different hosts to a central log server with `systemd-journal-remote` [link to software](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journal-remote.service.html). All journals are stored remotely in a file per host. Now I'd like to search in all of these journals with `journalctl` in case of an error that has occured.

So let's say I want look for the error message in all four journal files. I do so with:

```bash
journalctl -r --file=remote-10.0.0.1.journal --file=remote-10.0.0.2.journal --file=remote-10.0.0.3.journal --file=remote-10.0.0.4.journal --grep=<my_error_msg>
```

That works just fine. Problem is that the output is barely readable because of boot messages cluttering up the output:

```bash
-- Boot 9cb37f3f1f0f49c1a6c7aeafdc9ba9bf --
-- Boot 6e509dc14176465c975d564b1ac114cd --
-- Boot 9cb37f3f1f0f49c1a6c7aeafdc9ba9bf --
-- Boot 6e509dc14176465c975d564b1ac114cd --
-- Boot 9cb37f3f1f0f49c1a6c7aeafdc9ba9bf --
-- Boot 6e509dc14176465c975d564b1ac114cd --
-- Boot 9cb37f3f1f0f49c1a6c7aeafdc9ba9bf --
Dec 21 15:34:01 webserver-01 CRON[444444]: (root) CMD ((/var/www/heartbeat.sh "<my_error_msg>"))
-- Boot 6e509dc14176465c975d564b1ac114cd --
Dec 21 15:51:08 webserver-02 CRON[232323]: (root) CMD ((/var/www/heartbeat.sh "<my_error_msg>"))
-- Boot 9cb37f3f1f0f49c1a6c7aeafdc9ba9bf --
-- Boot 6e509dc14176465c975d564b1ac114cd --
-- Boot 9cb37f3f1f0f49c1a6c7aeafdc9ba9bf --
```

I guess the reason for this is because all boots of all hosts respected. I assume this because the output stays the same if I add the `--boot all` option. If I know want to reduce the journal entries to "since last boot" only I'd add the `-b 0` option. Problem: it gives me the results of the **latest** boot–i.e. the host which has bootet the last.

Is there a way get entries of all hosts after last boot? Or does anyone has a better idea to search through more than one journal for <text_string>?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. To remove the boot messages on can use the `-q` or `--quiet` attribute.

Note that `-m` or `--merge` attribute won't work with `--boot` option even though it removes the cluttering boot messages and solves the problem for non-last-boot scenarios :

```bash
journalctl -r --merge --grep=<search_string> --boot 0
Using --boot or --list-boots with --merge is not supported
```